# Terraform init copy from local cache instead of remote source

Tags: terraform

I have been cloning a pretty large project with dozen of different terraform stack.
Every time I run the terraform init on a new project, I go through the download of module phase which for some reason is quite long. But this is mostly the same module from on stack to an other.

Is there an option to use an internal cache, where instead of downloading from the remote source, it would copy it from my local computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have a local directory as a shared plugin cache. To do this, you must use the `plugin_cache_dir` setting in the [CLI configuration file](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/config-file), e.g.:

```
plugin_cache_dir   = "$HOME/.terraform.d/plugin-cache"
```

This [documentation page](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/config-file#provider-installation) describes the behavior:

> When a plugin cache directory is enabled, the terraform init command will still use the configured or implied installation methods to obtain metadata about which plugins are available, but once a suitable version has been selected it will first check to see if the chosen plugin is already available in the cache directory. If so, Terraform will use the previously-downloaded copy.